# How to write a simple react-native native module with a callback

Tags: android, react-native

How to get this work, in the simplest way, I have trouble getting the callback send to react-native, probably I'm missing something.

```
@ReactMethod
public void testCallback(Callback cb) {

String sampleText = "Java is fun";
int textLength = sampleText.length();
    try{
        cb.invoke(textLength);
    }catch (Exception e){
        cb.invoke("err");
    }
}
```

On react-native side

```
var getNativeCallback = require('react-native-native-callback');


getNativeCallback.testCallback(function (result){
    console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: I already solved it, just need to bridge with reactContenx by starting the reactContenx .startActivity, but I haven't post my own solution yet

Comment: Could you please post your solution to this?

Comment: github.com/amalChandran/ReactNative_Android_integration for examples related to callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to face the same problem, and finally I have to take a different approach, as apparently, there is no Callback type accepted for @ReactProp.

Instead I used the 'Events' way, in order to have response communication from Android native to React Native.

In the Android side I set up a SendEvent function conveniently fired as it needs:

```
private void sendEventToReactFromAndroid(ReactContext reactContext,String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap params) {
    reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(eventName, params);
}

@Override
public void customAndroidListenerFunction() {
    sendEvent(mcontext, "EventName", null);

}
```

Then in the React side, you will expect this event, and parameters if you may like:

```
var {DeviceEventEmitter} = require('react-native');
...
componentWillMount: function() {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('EventName', function(e: Event) {
        console.log("Received event loud and clear in the React Native side!");
    });
},
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi i have few doubts here. can we talk here ? I am having problem with this. I want to send some parameters to android native and get some object and parameter too at the same time .

Comment: Hi, have you checked the official RN page [Native Modules Android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android) ? Specifically that [Android React Native callbacks](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#callbacks)