# react native Callback

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

I am trying to pass callback func to my android native view but i get error. Can I pass callback to view as props or it is only available as invoking react method?

Here is my code:

Package.java

```
public class RMTGesturePackage implements ReactPackage {

@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
        new RMTGestureManager());
}
```

RMTGestureManager.java

```
   @ReactProp(name="onChangeCallback")
    public void onChange(RMTGlSurfaceView rmtGlSurfaceView, final      Callback onChangeCallback) {

}
```

NativeGesture.js

```
<NativeRMTGesture onChangeCallback={function(){}}/>
```

react-native run-android pass without error but on emulator i am getting "Unrecognized type: interface com.facebook.bridge.Callback for method : 
com.rmtgesture.RMTGestureManager#onChange"

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33325595/how-to-write-a-simple-react-native-native-module-with-a-callback/

Comment: https://github.com/amalChandran/ReactNative_Android_integration for examples related to callbacks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, currently they don't support callbacks in ReactProp annotated methods [ReactProp.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.40-stable/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/annotations/ReactProp.java#L21)

Use events instead! Example: [ReactSwitchManager.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.40-stable/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/switchview/ReactSwitchManager.java#L77)

Comment: Really? How is this not yet supported? Seems like such a basic feature